# Python If-statement "if something is in the row that is not 0, return..."

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have this project where I want to analyze how many poems I have written. In an excel sheet I created (amongst others) three columns. They are called "cleaned poem", "cleaned additional poem 1" and "cleaned additional poem 2". If I didn't write a poem or additional poems that day the cell contains a 0.

I want to write an if clause to return something if the value in the cell is 0 and something different if the value is not 0, hence contains a poem.

My previous attempt is this (it doesn't work, the colum that gets printed either shows the value "day with two poems" or "NaN").

```
    def poems_per_day(row):
if row ['cleaned poem'] == 0:
    return 'day without poem'
elif (row['cleaned poem'] is not None):
    return 'day with one poem'
if row ['cleaned additonal poem 1'] == 0:
    return 'day with one poem'
elif (row['cleaned additional poem 1'] is not None):
    return 'day with two poems'
if row ['cleaned additional poem 2'] == 0:
    return 'day with one poem'
elif (row['cleaned additional poem 1'] is not None):
    return 'day with two poems'
```

Comment: I am not sure how this function could return `NaN` as every return statement returns a string. But you could be getting an error related to `NaN`. Would it be possible to show a small modified sample of the excel file and how you are reading this into Python so that we can regenerate what you are getting?

Comment: can you provide a sample of the dataframe?

Comment: Are you sure it's the *integer* `0`, not the *string* `'0'`? If the column contains poems as strings alongside `0`, it could be all strings, so naturally `... == 0` returns `False` no matter what.

Comment: yes, you are right, it is a string '0'.

Comment: `if value != '0'` @DataVE

Answer (score 0):

The bug could be with certain values not falling in either of the `if` or `elif` conditions. Since your goal is just to check if the cell contains '0', perhaps you could just replace all the `elif` statements with an `else`.

For instance:

```
def poems_per_day(row):
    if str(row['cleaned poem']) == '0':
        return 'day without poem'
    else:
        return 'day with one poem'
    if str(row['cleaned additonal poem 1']) == '0':
        return 'day with one poem'
    else:
        return 'day with two poems'
    if str(row['cleaned additional poem 2']) == '0':
        return 'day with one poem'
    else:
        return 'day with two poems'
```

Comment: This doesn't work either, unfortunately. Now pandas doesn't even print the new column anymore.

Comment: @DataVE Hi, I've just read your comment that the '0' in the data cell is a string, not an integer. I've fixed the code to account for this - could you please check if the code works now? Thanks!

Comment: It worked, thanks! But in the end I also chose a cleaner logic.

Answer (score 0):

It is working now with this statement:

```
def poems_per_day_if_stat (row):
    if str(row['cleaned additional poem 2']) != '0':
        return 'day with three poems'
    elif str(row['cleaned additional poem 1']) != '0':
        return 'day with two poems'
    elif str(row['cleaned poem']) != '0':
        return 'day with one poem'
    else : 
        return 'day without poem'


poetry['poems per day if-stat'] = poetry.apply(lambda row: poems_per_day_if_stat(row), axis = 1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).